How can I go about getting customized icons to persist with updates
So, here's my situation:
I have went through and replaced the icon files for google chrome (among other apps) found in directories like these: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/[resolution]/apps/[app name] with my own custom images, with colors that match the theming of my desktop environment (don't ask why, I think its pretty, ok?). chrome is an apt-managed package, and whenever I run apt-get upgrade I have to replace those files all over again (as they get overwritten during the update). I've also tried going into the .desktop file and changing the filepath target for the icon, but this similarly gets overwritten on an update. I'm a relative noob to ubuntu/linux in general, so I'm asking here, even though perhaps this question isn't limited to the operating system. In any case, even though i'm not sure its possible, is there any way for me to set things up so that my custom icons persist on an update?

It is Google replacing the files. I suggest you check into that.

Copy the .desktop-files to ~/.local/share/applications/ and edit these copies with the path to your customized icons.

Totally forgot to get back to this like I meant to, but this is the answer! Thanks
